# How to add back button in tablayout

Tags: android, android-tablayout

Hi recently I have implemented a tabs layout in my app, I was also trying to implement back button on the action bar.

I was using this code

```
//back navigation
if(getSupportActionBar()!= null) {
  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  if(item.getItemId()==android.R.id.home){
    finish();
  }
  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

The code works just fine for the other activities, but it does not work for the tab activity.

Does anybody know why? Should I use a different code?

Thanks.

Comment: Well i don't think that there is support version of TabActivity with method getSupportActionBar(), Can you provide real code an more details

Answer (score 0):

Try to call if your activity extends TabActivity.

```
super.finish();
```